How to append specific column name to all the the values in same column in pandas?



Name
Place




Tyson
New York


Sophie
Seattle



I've tried various methods, but cant get the output as below:



Name
Place




Tyson
Place - New York


Sophie
Place - Seattle



I need to add only Place column header to all the values of that column.

df['Place'] = 'Place - ' + df['Place'].astype(str)
